# jQuery AJAX triggering too quickly

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asynchronous

I have a relatively simple jQuery AJAX call wrapped in a function and I am testing my error functionality. The problem I am facing is the AJAX call happens too quickly! It is causing my 'H6' and '.loading' elements to start repeating. The behaviour I require is to remove the elements, then call the ajax.

```
function getAvailability(form) {
    var str = $(form).serialize(),
    warning = $('#content h6');

    if ( warning.length > 0 ) {
        $(warning).remove();
        $('<div class="loading">Loading&hellip;</div>').insertAfter(form);
    }
    else
    {
        $('<div class="loading">Loading&hellip;</div>').insertAfter(form);
    }

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "someFile",
        data: str,

        success: function(calendar) {
            $('.loading').fadeOut(function() {
                $(this).remove();
                $(calendar).insertAfter(form).hide().fadeIn();
            });
        },
        error: function() {
            $('.loading').fadeOut(function() {
                $('<h6>Unfortunately there has been an error and we can not show you the availability at this time.</h6>').insertAfter(form);
            });
        }
    });

    return false;
}
```

I would love to sequence it like so -> Remove 'warning' from page, add .loading. Then trigger AJAX. Then fade out .loading, add & fade in warning/calendar dependent on success.

---

I have amended my original code, and I have got the function to behave as expected, primarily because I have disabled the submit button during the ajax process.

```
function getAvailability(form) {
    var str = $(form).serialize(),
    btn = $('#property_availability');

    // Disable submit btn, remove original 'warning', add loading spinner
    btn.attr("disabled", "true");
    $('.warning').remove();
    $('<div class="loading">Loading&hellip;</div>').insertAfter(form);

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "public/ajax/returnAvailability1.php",
        data: str,

        success: function(calendar) {
            $('.loading').fadeOut(function() {
                $(this).remove();
                $(calendar).insertAfter(form).hide().fadeIn();
            });
        },
        error: function() {
            $('.loading').fadeOut(function() {
                $(this).remove();
                $('<h6 class="warning">Unfortunately there has been an error and we can not show you the availability at this time.</h6>').insertAfter(form);
                btn.removeAttr("disabled");
            });
        }
    });

    return false;
}
```

I believe that the original sequence was not working as expected due to the time delay created by the fadeOut() functions.

Comment: It isn't possible for your ajax to start before warning is removed the way your current code is written. If you are seeing otherwise, it might be a rendering issue, or you are using `async: false` in `ajaxSetup` somewhere. Also, `$(warning).remove` should be `warning.remove`

Comment: you could wrap your ajax inside of a `setTimeout` or dont put it in the same function as the warning remove

Comment: Also, `if ( warning.length > 0 )` is unnecessary in this case.

Comment: What calls your getAvailability method?

Comment: Thanks for all the tips. I can not provide full feedback on my code till I get to work on Monday... but heres some more info. I am working locally, specifically trying to trigger my error msg with a wrong URL on the ajax call. So getting a 404 on purpose. The getAvailability function is triggered on a form submit (click event).

Answer (score 2):

Instead of adding and removing `warning`, why not just show/hide leveraging ajaxStart and ajaxStop?

```
warning.ajaxStart(function() {
    $(this).show();
}).ajaxStop(function() {
    $(this).fadeOut();
});
```

Comment: I was unaware of this. I will certainly try it out and report back.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to sequence your events, then you should try using the deferred and promise methods that are a part of the jQuery.ajax API.  This article does a good job of introducing them: http://www.bitstorm.org/weblog/2012-1/Deferred_and_promise_in_jQuery.html

Comment: really no need for that if you just want the script to follow the default sequence...